# How to interpret this correlogram?

Tags: correlation

I'd like to have insights about how to interpret the following correlogram.

It is supposed to show the correlation between several themes/threats which were proposed as answers in a survey about the oceans, but I do not know how to correctly describe, interpret and report what it says...

Any help greatly appreciated, thank you very much !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a confusing diagram. It shows pairwise correlation values between different features. Correlation values range from +1 in dark blue to -1 in dark red. It's much easier to interpret if you just look at the colors and ignore the pies entirely.

The pie charts in each cell are a secondary way of showing the correlation value, essentially reiterating what the color already tells you, but in a much more confusing way. We have a 100% filled pie for correlation values of +1, as seen along the diagonal. Correlation values of -1 seem to be denoted by a 1/4 filled in pie, as seen in "Toxic was discharge" vs. "Noise pollution", but that convention defies any logic I can think of. Correlation values of 0 are denoted by a 2/3 filled in pie, which also doesn't really make any sense.

This chart was made with very odd conventions for the lower bound of correlation as shown in the pie charts. It seems whoever made the diagram realized they couldn't show a 0% filled in pie for a correlation of -1 as it wouldn't show any color except the border, so they arbitrarily fixed the lower bound of -1 to a 1/4 filled in pie. It's not a very good visualization, as it shows completely redundant information between the color and pie size, and the pie charts present the information in a way that is more confusing than helpful. I'd argue the chart would have been far clearer with just colored cells and no pies at all.

A more typical convention would be to have a 100% dark blue circle for a correlation of +1, progressively lightening and emptying down to 0% filled (white) for zero correlation, and then filling in with increasingly dark shades of red until reaching a 100% dark red circle to denote a correlation of -1. The pies as shown defy logic and convention, and only make things more confusing.

Comment: Thank you so much for this very helpful answer ! Indeed I tried it this way and it is much better !